# Plot discrete values with different color

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Given a dataframe with discrete values,

```
d=data.frame(id=1:6, a=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), b=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), c=c(10,20,30,30,10,20))
```

I want to make a plot like

[image]

However I want to make different color for each layer, say red and green for "a", yellow/blue for "b".

Comment: how do you determine the color gradient? from what i see on the picture the 6 rectangle on line `a` should have `light blue - light blue - light blue - dark blue - dark blue - dark blue` (the values are `1 1 1 0 0 0`)

Comment: this is just a random example what I want to achieve. The point is to fill the boxes with different color according to datafram.

Comment: Did you try `geom_tile`?

Comment: yes but I can not get different colors for different rows!!

Comment: Please update your post with your current code, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to reshape your data (define coordinates to draw the rectangles) in order to use `geom_rect` from `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

i = setNames(expand.grid(1:nrow(d),1:ncol(d[-1])),c('x1','y1'))

ggplot(cbind(i,melt(d, id.vars='id')), 
       aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x1+1, ymin=y1,  ymax=y1+1, color=variable, fill=value)) + 
       geom_rect()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `geom_tile()`. But you need to reshape your data to get exactly the same figure as you presented.

```
df  <- data.frame(id=factor(c(1:6)), a=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), b=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), c=c(10,20,30,30,10,20))
    library(reshape2)

    df <- melt(df, vars.id  = c(df$id))

       library(ggplot2)
        ggplot(aes(x = id, y = variable, fill = value), data = df) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First we use `reshape2` to transform the data from wide to long. Then to get discrete values we use `as.factor(value)` and finally we use `scale_fill_manual` to assign the 5 different colours we need. In `geom_tile` we specify the colour of the tile borders.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(id=1:6, a=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), b=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), c=c(10,20,30,30,10,20))    
df <- melt(df, id.vars=c("id"))
ggplot(df, aes(id, variable, fill = as.factor(value))) + geom_tile(colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "steelblue2", "steelblue3", "steelblue4", "darkblue"), name = "Values")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = 1:6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
require("dplyr")
require("tidyr")
require("ggplot2")

d=data.frame(id=1:6, a=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), b=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), c=c(10,20,30,30,10,20))

ggplot(d %>% gather(type, value, a, b, c) %>% mutate(value = paste0(type, value)), 
       aes(x = id, y = type)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "indianred", "lightgoldenrod1", 
                               "royalblue", "plum1", "plum2", "plum3"))
```

[image]